# How to append files in Stata from the same dir and folder that start with the same letter?

Tags: stata

I have a folder called Workdata. In this folder I have the following files.

> 1. Mydata_biology
> 2. Mydata_chemisty
> 3. Mydata_math
> 4. uncleandata_1
> 5. uncleandata_2

If I wanted to append all the files in this folder I can use the following code :

```
local allfiles : dir "Data\scores" files "*"

foreach f in local allfiles {
*append loop
}
```

However when i try to append only the first 3 that start with Mydata I can no longer use local allfiles

I tried the following code, but it did not work:

```
local allfiles : dir "Data\scores" files "Mydata*"

foreach f in local allfiles {
*append loop
}
```

Comment: Also, the software is called Stata, not STATA. This really gets some people's goats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a loop. This is pretty easy with user-written `fs`:

```
cd "Data/scores" 
ssc install fs
fs "Mydata*.dta"
append using `r(files)'
```

Comment: I tried your method, but it did not work. I am getting ancould not rename c:\ado\plus\stata.trk to c:\ado\plus\backup.trk
r(699);

 error message.

Comment: @sonu I am guessing that the file attributes for backup.trk are read-only. Try changing that to archive.

Comment: Another route might be to `sysdir set PLUS "H:\mypath"`, where you change the path to something suitable.

Answer (score 1):

The foreach loop is not correctly setup. You want

```
foreach f of local ...
```

and you have

```
foreach f in local ...
```

There's a difference, and it's important. Check `help foreach`, if needed.